# WSO2 BPS - dynamic BPEL?

Tags: wso2, bpel

Is it possible to have a dynamic BPEL process that load part of the process depending on process variables or we have to code the whole parametric process in one big bundle?
It could be usefull to be able to instantiate subprocesses at some time that are not part of the parent one.

If possible any tutorial or hint?

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic bpel is not supported within wso2 bps. One option is to break your process in the multiple processes and invoke those within the bpel depending on the logic flow.

Regards
Nandika